# jQuery - Click() doesn't work when clicking a <li> in an <ul>

Tags: jquery

Trying to click an item in a dynamically-generated list, but the `$.click()` function just won't fire.

HTML for the list:

```
<div>
    <ul id="site_list"> </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery to generate the list (which works as intended, generating a long list of data with the desired class attribute):

```
var sites =[];
    $.getJSON("php/ABC.php", function(result){
        $.each(result.Sites, function(i,v){
            sites.push('<li class="site" id="site_'+ ABC + '</li>');
        });

        $('#site_list').append(sites.join(''));
    });
```

jQuery to be triggered when clicking a list (doesn't work...it doesn't throw errors...just fails to respond. I've tried `$('#site')` as well, to no avail. I suspect it's due to the method I'm using to generate the `<ul>`...something is preventing the DOM from properly recognizing each element inside the UL.:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("site_selected");
});
```

Comment: read the [jQuery FAQ page](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_..._.3F).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#site_list').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("site_selected");
});
```

As you're addling `li` dynamically so you need delegate event handler to `li`.

---

#### Note

Delegate event structure of **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** is like following:

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```

Here `container` point to a `Static-element` that contains the `target` element and belongs to DOM at page load.

Comment: wahoo! that did it...thanks!

one more question, then: how could I remove the "site_selected" class from every other 'li' in the list when I click on a new one? (so only 1 'li' has that class at a time?)

Comment: you are my super hero! my head smoky while thinking this trouble. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The above code looks fine. I just dealt with the same issue and **thecodeparadox** hit the nail on the head.  The input is being loaded dynamically, so it won't work if we put that code in the $(document).ready(function(){...} before it exists.

Just put this code...

```
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("site_selected");
    });
```

after the list is dynamically generated in the same function (not in doc ready function).  If the on-click function is created before the elements are initialized it's a no-go.

There might be an advantage to doing it the other way:

```
    $('#site_list').on('click', 'li', function(){
```

However, it's working great for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try 'on' instead of 'click'.

```
$('li').on('click', function(){ $(this).toggleClass('site_selected') } );
```

Comment: This won't help, because the .click() method is a shortcut to exactly what you've shown. (You *can* solve the problem with .on(), but not like that.)